# How to select facebook 'notes' posted via application

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

There is an application using FQL. Is there an opportunity to select notes posted by the application with the known id? As far as I know, there is no field 'app_id' in the 'note' table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use graph api to get the notes of an app by app_id. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note/  you have to use any valid access token.

### Example using php-sdk 3.1.1

```
<?php 
$app_access = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=AppId&client_secret=YOURSECRET&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_access_token = file_get_contents($app_access);
$pageid="your_app_or_page_id";
$MEnotes = $facebook->api('/'.$pageid.'/notes/?$app_access_token');
foreach ($MEnotes as $key=>$value) {
foreach ($value as $fkey=>$fvalue) {
        $noteID=$fvalue[id];
        $noteSubject=$fvalue[subject];
        $noteMessage=$fvalue[message];
        echo ''.$noteID.'<b>  '.$noteSubject.'</b><br />'.$noteMessage.'<hr />';
}};    
 ?>
```